# Intentional Suggestion as Warning

Tags: new-job, company-culture

I just got a new job in a different city in a state with at-will employment at a very small company. 
My first day at work, a colleague who is close to my boss messages me suggesting a sublet/room that only lasts for two months. I was looking for places for the long run.

Is it possible that is an indirect signal from my boss that I could get fired if my performance is not to their liking? Or am I reading into this too much?

Comment: Or you could reply "How do you mean? What's the advantage?"

Comment: In a city  you don't know, a short let is a great ideal as it gives to time to get to know the city before committing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think **you're reading way too much into this**.

A two month sublet might be an excellent place to stay *while you look for your real home*.

Finding the best house/apartment/condo/whatever is not something done over night.

Answer (score 14):

If anything I think that is a good sign.  People don't try to help out people or get involved in their living arrangement if they don't like the person or think the person would get fired.

It is very natural to scope an area out for a month or two before signing a long-term lease or buying something.  It sounds to me like boss's friend is hooking you up.  You can read more into it but that is how I would read it.

Comment: I'd take it as a good sign as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think your reading to much into it.

Buying a house takes months, maybe years, depending on "things".

Finding a good apartment to rent can take even longer. I was waiting 3 years to get into my dream apartment.

A short lease is a good first step. You don't want to be tied to a 12 month lease when your dream house comes on market.

Most apartments in this area will not even rent to you unless you have been at your current job for several months, and have good history. If you have a bad history or are new in the area, then your not going to get a good apartment.

I would see this as someone trying to help out, and nothing more.